# Timestamp from Android device in the format hh:mm:ss:SS

Tags: android, timestamp, android-sensors

I have a requirement to log the sensor data in Android. In order to store the values in a Database, I need the timestamp as primary key in the format - hh:mm:ss:SS, where SS represents millisecond value. When I tried to use SensorEvent.timestamp(using the code below), I was unable to get the millisecond from Date class.

```
    long currTimeRelativeToBoot = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    long currTimeAbsolute = System.currentTimeMillis();
    double mStartTimeAbsoluteS = ((double)(currTimeAbsolute - currTimeRelativeToBoot))/(double)1000.0;
    double temp = mStartTimeAbsoluteS+((double)event.timestamp)/1000000000.0;
    Date time=new java.util.Date((long)temp*1000);
```

Is it possible to get the current time from the Android device in the format hh:mm:ss:SS?
Or what is the alternative for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use SimpleDateFormat, see tutorial [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/SimpleDateFormat.htm). But it's not recommended this approach, if you save it as a long, you can compare it, order, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you share an example snippet of how to do this? @gabi

Comment: public static final SimpleDateFormat SDF_ISO_DATE = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

 public static String formatISODate(long time) {
        return SDF_ISO_DATE.format(new Date(time));
    }

Comment: When I used the format "HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", I am getting 10:23:48.000+0200. Is it possible to get the  timestamp in the format present in the Logcat like 10.26.56.080. I hope the last denotes millisecond value. These differ when each time onSensorChanged() method is called, so that I can use this as primary key value. @gabi