# Convert TimeStamp String to DayName-Month-year at 4:00 pm in android?

Tags: java, android, date, time

i am stuck at this ,i have timestamp as string variable , and i want to convert it to this pattern DayName-Month-year at 04:00 pm ,the problem is i am targeting older version of android so when  use SimpleDateFormat it shows error as required higher android API .
please help

Comment: [SimpleDateFormat was added in API level 1](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat).

Comment: *"i have timestamp as string variable"* In what format? --- *"i am targeting older version of android"* What API level? --- *"it shows error"* What error? Show us. --- *"DayName-Month-year at 04:00 pm"* So `Mon-Jan-2018 at 04:00 pm`? That doesn't look right.

Comment: Have you solved it or haven't?

Comment: Frankly I don’t know the exact API level requirement, but even for low API levels you may add [the ThreeTenABP library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Andoird project and use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. Since the old-fashioned `SimpleDateFormat` is so notoriously troublesome, it may be worth considering.

Comment: Formatting date-time values on Android (and Java) have been covered many many times already. Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Comment: More duplicates: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20311306/642706), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14890388/642706), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/454315/642706), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30340308/642706), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32911677/642706).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting API error, It's because you imported android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat instead of java.text.SimpleDateFormat.

Useful links: [Convert time value to format “hh:mm Am/Pm” using Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084474/convert-time-value-to-format-hhmm-am-pm-using-android)

```
Date dt = new Date(date1);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy hh:mm a");
String time1 = sdf.format(dt);
```

OR

```
Date date = new Date();
String strDateFormat = "dd:MM:yyyy hh:mm a";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);
String time1 = sdf.format(date);
```

Comment: great , thank u so much , it was import issue

Comment: Happy to help you, please vote up If my answer helps you thank you :)

Comment: I will improve it later.

Comment: These troublesome classes were supplanted by the *java.time* classes. For older Android, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* and the *ThreeTenABP* projects.